# What is the difference between rendering full.html and partial.html with django and htmx, especially context variable

Tags: django, render, htmx

These are all parts of the demo.

#views.py

```py
def full(request):
    template_name = "htmxx/full.html"
    number        = 0
    form          = Number(request.POST or None, auto_id='id_%s'+str(number))
    context       = {"form": form, 'number': number }
    print("context  :", context)

    if request.method == "POST":
        pprint.pprint(request.POST.lists())

    return render(request, template_name, context)

def partial(request, zn):
    template_name = "htmxx/partial.html"
    number        = zn + 1
    form          = Number(auto_id='id_%s'+str(number))
    context       = {"form": form, 'number': number }
    print('context  :', context)

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path(''                 , views.nav     , name='nav'    ),
    path('nav'              , views.nav     , name='nav'    ),
    path('full'             , views.full    , name='full'   ),
    path('partial/<int:zn>' , views.partial , name='partial'),
]
```

#full.html

```html
...
        <div class="resp-table">

                <div class="resp-table-row">
                        <form class="resp-table-row" action="{% url 'full' %}" method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <div id="numberadd" >
                                        <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                        {% include "./partial.ht ml" %}
                                                </li>
                                        </ul>
                                </div>
                                <button class="table-header-cell" type="submit">input form</button>
                        </form>
                </div>
        
                <div class="resp-table-header">
                        <button class="table-header-cell" 
                                hx-get="{% url 'partial' zn=number %}" hx-target="#numberadd" hx-swap="beforeend" type="button">
                               create form  
                        </button>
                </div>
        
        </div>

{% endblock %}
```

#partial.ht ml

```html
{% for field in form %}                         
    {{ field }}
{% end_for %}
```

In full.html {{ number }} is 1. It works as expected.
In full.html extended with partial.ht ml {{ number }} stay 1, not updated too 2.

Where is context from partial rendering?

Comment: please include the html files too and urls.py how you access these views

Answer (score 0):

The distinction is nicely explained in django-htmx library [docs](https://django-htmx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips.html#partial-rendering).

Partial rendering view is same as full, but rendering using different (simpler) template. So the context returned can be the same. So in your case I would recommend merging full and partial views and just distinct the template:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.http import require_GET


@require_GET
def partial_rendering(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    if request.htmx:
        base_template = "_partial.html"
    else:
        base_template = "_base.html"

    ...

    return render(
        request,
        "page.html",
        {
            "base_template": base_template,
            # ...
        },
    )
```

Then in the template (page.html), use that variable in {% extends %}:

```
{% extends base_template %}

{% block main %}
  ...
{% endblock %}
```

Here, _base.html would be the main site base:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      ...
    </nav>
  </header>
  <main id="main">
    {% block main %}{% endblock %}
  </main>
</body>
```

whilst _partial.html would contain only the minimum element to update:

```
<main id="main">
  {% block main %}{% endblock %}
</main>
```